# Setting DSCP on a per-socket base

Tags: c, linux, networking, qos, setsockopt

There are several examples about using iptable to set the DSCP field of the the IP packets. I am trying not to use iptables, but to set the DSCP field just on a few selected sockets.

By reading `man 7 ip`, I found out that I can use something like

```
int tos_local = 0x28;
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS,  &tos_local, sizeof(tos_local));
```

There is one thing that it is not clear to me. `IP_TOS` is described to work on the old Type-Of-Service field, which has been redefined by [RFC2474](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2474) to be used by Differentiated Services.

So, my question is: can I use `setsockopt` with `IPPROTO_IP` and `IP_TOS` to set any DSCP value between 0 and 63, or am I limited to just `IPTOS_LOWDELAY`, `IPTOS_THROUGHPUT`, `IPTOS_RELIABILITY` and `IPTOS_MINCOST`?

Comment: Understand that simply setting the DSCP on a packet actually does nothing unless the network devices are configured to treat the packets based on DSCP, which they are not going to do by default. That is why QoS doesn't work across the public Internet. The QoS policies for a site can be very different. For example, you may think that marking a packet as `EF` would get you the best treatment, but a network could be configured to give such a packet the lowest priority, instead of the highest priority. In fact, many switches will remark traffic to `BE`.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/48179/8499) explains more about IP and QoS, and there are a lot of QoS questions and answers on [networkengineering.se].